# php forced download modifying file

Tags: php, download, web

I'm using php to force the download of .bz2 archives and .deb files for a webservice I'm making, but after downloading the files are invalid. I opened both the original file and the file downloaded through php in a text editor and I noticed that the one downloaded with php had 1 extra space at the beginning of the file, after removing that space the files did work. What could be causing this?

here is the code I'm using:

```
header('Content-Type: package/x-generic');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
ob_flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

I already tried experimenting with different headers and the clean and flush functions.

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Prefix `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to get an informative message if the extra space was caused by premature output. Also hexeditor, or binary diff.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an extra space after a `?>` in some of you php files. It is generally a good idea to omit closing `?>` tags to avoid this problem.

If that's the case you could use [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/headers_sent) after `flush()` to know from which file/line the extra space comes from.

Comment: or just put `/*` after the exit :-)

Comment: the extra byte appears at the begining of the downloaded file, so the problem comes from a previously included file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your PHP file(s) are saved as UTF-8 with a BOM ([Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). Try saving your php files as UTF-8 without a BOM. Any reasonably advanced text-editor will allow you to save files as UTF-8 without a BOM.

Also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833186/how-do-i-stop-zf-from-sending-a-empty-character-at-the-beginning/6833466#6833466) to another question that is related to this. It also mentions what [arnaud576875](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165226/php-forced-download-modifying-file/7165258#7165258) talks about as being a possible cause of the problem.

Comment: OP has only one extrat byte in his files, isn't the BOM more than one byte ?

Comment: @arnaud576875: hmm yeah, good point; I believe it is actually, yes.

Comment: @arnaud576875: Although the Wikipedia article I referred to says that, it should otherwise be interpreted as a zero-width non-breaking space. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-breaking_space also says, when the BOM mark is encountered elsewhere, it should, according to Unicode, be treated as a zero-width non-breaking space. I can image this will still be treated as a single empty character by some text-editors then.

Comment: BOM is 2 or 3 bytes. 0xFE, 0xFF for UTF-16. 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF for UTF-8 (though UTF-8 doesn't have a byte order, so a BOM is mostly useless).

Answer (score 0):

If you have whitespace before a php tag that could cause the space at the beginning. If you need output buffering (ob_clean(), ob_flush()) chances are there is a space or data getting output somewhere prior to setting the headers.  Turn off output buffering if possible and you should get an error telling what line the output started.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the solution to my problem, after a long search I found out that I was including another php file into my php file, that file had an space behind the ?> tag. :S Thanks to everyone who answered